# Map types against object keys? Get type depending on sibling classes?

Tags: typescript

##### Question

Is there a way to map types/interfaces to the **types of object instances**? Essentially like a `map` with the objects as the keys and types as the values.

##### Example

```js
type StringKeys = {
    foo: "foo" | "Foo",
    bar: "bar" | "Bar"
}

function fooBar<T extends keyof StringKeys>(s: T, t: StringKeys[T]) {}

// Maps types correctly
fooBar('foo', 'Foo') 
fooBar('bar', 'Bar') 
// fooBar('bar', 'foo') ❌ 

/* --- GOAL --- */
class Buzz{
    name: string

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    greet() {
        console.log(`Hi, I'm ${this.name}`)
    }

    getTitle():string {
        return `Senior commander ${this.name}`
    }
}

class Foo extends Buzz{
    constructor(name: string) {
        super(name);
    }

    getTitle():string {
        return `Professor ${this.name} the Fourth`
    }
}

class Bar extends Buzz{
    constructor(name: string) {
        super(name);
    }

    getTitle():string {
        return `${this.name} the one and only.`
    }
}

type GetValues<T extends Foo|Bar> = T extends Foo ? 'Foo' : T extends Bar ? 'Bar' : never

function fooBarObj<T extends Foo|Bar>(s: T, t: GetValues<T>){};

fooBarObj(new Foo('foo'), 'Foo')
fooBarObj(new Bar('bar'), 'Bar') // <- Error, expects 'Foo'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=55&ssc=60&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwNIRAZygXigG8AoKMqAMwHsqAuKAImqoagB9GAxGhgGlPIAjAIbx6DEfFYcGAIVENiAX2LEKAV2QBjYIirJKNefAA8AFSgQAHsAjIAJrgDWWKhVgIUGLNgB8ACmx6M14oYHo4JDRMHABtMwBdAEoiFWIAenSoAFlhMFxQSFwtKnh4CB0AGxA1I1F-AHJmBtCG7ioGlNqqY0bJFqgG406oDKzmXob+1uaUwBlyUYyAKigAWnWoAHEAeQBBABk1jaX04i1K4WxcWXUAL1uScihkYQBbCHpsTzRVJ5LkL7wdQ6Ur+F7vT7fVApR5PcjAAAWiGwADpwdACOiANwCMhpJ6ocoQYD+GG4uH-bBUSoQFGVKiofwAAwAEohQgBJBqvKAAEkIiORaLeECUTKS5Px5FQxLMiGANNJtEBXiI5Ke5WA6ngBiZMDsengUBKr1ewgcECN-MFqPRYslylU50uuHalhsdkcUBu91hZEpCGBwFB6MhUWharh5Gw6kg8DBIqSOKeUrIMuAcoVECVKrQkajUE12t1AAV4G4IFdSnyBUjbSKlGEEdBuNrEUyHWlnVdvaJ3bYHNc7g9yQGgSD46GoLmI364TG4wn3kmHeT05nFUllVD81GizqoEzrXXhe9G4joPpoOb7FB9NUUR2U47iIVoJtiQA1YSVdSV8z9p6ro0Gwxi+PgUAWNYA5em6AD8gztA0UDBIBg69kaCFDKIyH0MgEAAG6WqoGjaLo+iGD0ojbIIABWAHQUBUDtKBogBEEkGhOEWxfj+f7YOYvhJIQSg4t0xg0bRYIQAA7sxNCNLMrRIRKEzUXR0lyZM-RJK0wwpJkUAmKsUAAKJlKUoTWJAOi4G0NANEAA)

##### My Use Case

My ultimate goal is similar to the example. I want to define a function which accepts a parameter that's an instance of one of many sibling classes, and augments the type of the second parameter according to the specific class of the first parameter.

Comment: Unless you want the question to be primarily about structural typing, then you should not use empty classes in your examples. [They behave strangely](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) for the reason you mention: they are indistinguishable from the type system.  Could you [edit] to add some distinguishing properties to `Foo` and `Bar` here and remove the second section so we can focus on a single issue?

Comment: Done @jcalz! With my use case, each subclass has the same properties but override the methods, so I emulated that here. Also, I've found that when the objects' shapes are different, typescript can differentiate between instances of different subclasses, but when they're the same, there's no true way to differentiate between them, even though they're of different types, even according to TS.

Comment: @Brother58697 OK, these classes ain't empty anymore but they are still identical. There's no difference in their interface.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment.  The inability of the compiler to tell apart two identically-shaped object types is intentional.  If you want the compiler to care you need to distinguish them structurally in some way, such as with a literally-typed property as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxxXKm).  Does that fully address your question?  If so I'll write this up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @Brother58697 check this out [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQHZgLYFNoBeaAIgXlIG5UBfVVUSGAITACcV1McDiy27anQYA3DtDAAuOIn5Z8Ad2iCAFAEoa4zgCN+ybHnwzSkACYAzUtFpaJwGYP467nM1IAuATwAO+eBbQeiQKyhQaNKgA9FHQHgAW+F6S7IRgICBxidD4AB5gwB7QEEZxvoQAhKhAA)

Comment: Thank you both for your replies! I have a better idea of how types are used in TS thanks to you! It's about being type safe and not throwing errors, hence shape being what matters, since neither would throw errors if replaced with each other in any implementation. @jcalz I ended up also adding a read only property. Not directly to distinguish, but to actually read and use as a key in an object, but it's good to know that it also distinguishes the types!

Comment: @jcalz, please post your explanation and workaround as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is largely [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), where types are compared by their shape/structure, as opposed to a [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) type system where types are compared by their name/declaration site.  If you're familiar with nominal type systems like Java's, then structural typing might be confusing.  After all, in Java, two classes are just *different*, even if they have the same fields and methods.  But in TypeScript, two types with the same structure are *the same*, even the instance types of two classes with separate declarations.  Structural typing has lots of benefits (which are probably off topic here) but there are times when people want to use nominal or nominal-like typing.

There's a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#202](https://github.com/Microsoft/Typescript/issues/202) to support nominal typing, and there are a few techniques you can use to get behavior like this.

---

One is mentioned [in the TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible); add a "brand" member to each type to distinguish it from others.    For example,  you can add a member named `type` whose value is of a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types):

```
class Foo extends Buzz {

    readonly type = "Foo";
    // (property) Foo.type: "Foo"

    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }   
    getTitle(): string { return `Professor ${this.name} the Fourth` }
}

class Bar extends Buzz {

    readonly type = "Bar";
    // (property) Bar.type: "Bar"

    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }    
    getTitle(): string { return `${this.name} the one and only.` }
}
```

Here `Foo` class instances have a `type` property of type `"Foo"`, while `Bar` class instances have a `type` property of type `"Bar"`.  Since `"Foo"` and `"Bar"` are different types, then `Foo` and `Bar` are different types, and your code will consistently be able to distinguish them.  (Note that by making the fields [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#readonly) it causes the compiler to infer string literal types from the initializer instead of the wider `string` type, which would not be distinguishable.)

---

Another approach that works specifically with classes is to give them [`private` or `protected` members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes):

```
class Foo extends Buzz {

    private nom = true;

    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }   
    getTitle(): string { return `Professor ${this.name} the Fourth` }
}

class Bar extends Buzz {

    private nom = true;    

    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }    
    getTitle(): string { return `${this.name} the one and only.` }
}
```

Private and protected class members are one of the few places where TypeScript actually cares about declaration site, so `Foo` and `Bar` are now distinguishable even though the both have the same structure.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.0.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhATiYATJBvAUEkUvADYhRSoCuAXrXocc6JAFxJQAuaAlsAHN8TZkXgB7YNzTV4XcWgAUrCB2n8BASkajdSLgAteUAHQqkAXiQqA3CNEBfYXqQC0ECF0XaCL5hKlxUggTUnEBRQADAAleABokAEkAcjAkABJcQ2MzcAgHSM17Zidi4gFPABVeLmDvNR4NHT8idy5qNGAkSIBlCGBeBRJxMDBMLAg0DKyjUxUCsqInEudiMgoqADFxcSQIAA8ufqwqFDoGAkWkdxAsSVIAT30HmGQrACJt8Xe7FwB6P5IRQwNDiV5oLgPbRfEyQ14cT47d6rXQBaSyeRKFQNPiCHxXZhQajg5R5TS-PSlFwVLjVWoQeqcRqCZotNodLqRAAKoIAZtAoENMtk5nkHPoDMhth1DJErstiFS1uRKKgQFMDkdsKdzowrjc7sBHs9XpYkO8UOqflcAUCQWDJpDtJa0LCXqpzS7kVc0TwMQpSewmbitKy-ESSSpyfKUaIaXS6pocU1fC1rp4Od1hbNcpBxYZkJJkOMkPcHiY5S4FUtY3DkABxTwANRApGo0AAPJU9odjlsdkgAD5qtAAPjN3c1faQXyQAH4kMkvskkBxJ73tSP54uXSuOMAIAA3Sax3nUYByQZdXk7F0AeQARgArLs9rUnGcD4cu0eKKBrhIuA4RsuBbNtO0qUcfCQBw7HsG9xHvZ9lAgAB3T9xEUZIEOSTQEiXHZcPg291UfJ8UPQl0sIfdVcPw3cinwUoVFgBBkB5XhDxAI4w3WVUznoMMWDyZNBFjfxJHROQA2xYMNHxNMJRycwrFsGMrjcDwvAUtM0SCEIwgiGJ4iSVJphFXN8kKdTqSqGpE1EgQhL0dlOm6PoBiGCRRnGSZzJzeZK0pewlTEFV+12KdNwEi5xOIEFOO45BgBGM0-QgOCXF9GRpKxES5LxZzdAjSZAwgaMqzioh43shkkwKpzUzZDM3O5PkBSFGZlLFCUpXEGUDCC3Rqxg2M+NOdU32nGK9RcBKuJ4lK0isdLMr0bL-TyoN1EKprw2JUqowpYaqtcOz6UZHbGoJYhXM5bNurzXrSwPJASzLCsYxWew6yQECwPbKBXyij9Z2-dVxysdd3wi7cCPEPckGh6bJoXZJd1XawjxPeDz0vSQkAQpCX2RzcwZHX9-yRwDgObVtAa7KC8BgtaiCJ0jkIPdCviwnC8MXZcimYdm0DIiiR2o2j+fRqXhAcIA)

Comment: Wish I could up vote this twice. Excellent answer and very informative! The private member case is interesting and makes a lot of sense. Since they're not accessible from the outside, then they're not *technically* part of the shape but inner methods can access and use them, making it possible to hit type errors if classes are exchanged in certain cases. Like if in `Foo` there's a private array that a method pushed elements into. Of course this is predicated on the compiler being blind to their type, so I'm not sure if my understanding is all that correct .